# How to find real line from the pattern of lines. Find real x data points of a line based on the pattern lines drawn?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, linegraph

I have lines Eg:- line-1, line-2 ,...n with same pattern of an error on y-axis(Errors) at different points of (x-axis) (Location points).

I want to superimpose those lines to find the correct location of x.

I'm collecting data points of error 'y' on path 'x'. Every month I collect those data points (x,y) on same path. All the data points are created by machine. Point to remember, Machine always doesn't give correct x' location of y error point'.
if I plot first month data points it gives me a line. And if I plot second month data points on same plane I see that due to machines mistake, error value is shown behind or after the previous month error but in real that y error point is at original location x.

In simple words, I see an error-y occurred on point-x for the first time in a path & second time when I plot the error with new values (x,y) on same path. I see error-y occurred at different x point. When we look at graph we can clear say that same error is formed on second month also but at different location. Now I want to find real line with correct x location points at of error y using line1,line2 (x,y)  points data.

Real line (x,y) or superimposed line :  consider a point from line 1 = (2,4.5) I can see same kind of point on line2 =(2.4,4.6) which was drawn with data points after a month time of same path. where because of some machine error in real world , errors of those points are placed in incorrect x location points. but in real those error points Y (y1,y2) should be at x point (x1 point of line1)=x2 point of line2). like line1=(2,4.5) and line2=(2,4.6).

**code Snippet to understand the problem**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs=np.arange(0, 10)

y1= [3,   3.5, 5,   4.5, 5.5, 7.2, 6.1, 4.1, 3, 4.5]
y2= [3.5, 4,   5.5, 4,   5.6, 7.2, 6.6, 4.5, 3, 4.5]

plt.plot(xs, y1, label="line1")
plt.plot(xs, y2, label="line2")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Now I want find a line that will have real values (x,y) from the patterns lines(line 1 and line 2).

present line patterns of Line-1 and Line2

[image: ![present line patterns of Line-1 and Line2]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but consider averaging values of y1, y2, ...

Comment: It's so unclear want you are trying to do. Please clearly define what you mean by 'real' x and y...

Comment: @Julien updated the question

Comment: @Mr.T please check

Comment: Nope, I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Your explanation is "line 1 is the correct line, line 2 is incorrect, how do I find the correct line?". I would say "line 1 as you explained". So, what else do you want to do now?

Comment: @Mr.T line 1 also not a correct line. line 1 and line 2 are pattern lines means looks alike when you see as individual line graphs on different planes  but at different points of ( x,y) when we plot them on same plane.